# Java GUI add text and i want to italic , bold the word l. How can is it?

Tags: java

I want to make java application with gui for add story, In my application there are text area for insert a story. I want my app have italic, bold etc for add story.

How to do it?

Comment: **I** don't understand. *What* should be italic? ***Where***? What's preventing this? *How can is it?* Talk to the people at Campbell's soup, maybe they ***can*** help.

Comment: The answer would depend on which GUI toolkit / components are being used. For example, AWT has no component that supports rich text (that mixes fonts or font styles in the one component). Swing has some components that allow rich text (e.g. `JLabel` or `JEditorPane`) and others that don't (e.g. `JTextArea`). For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) including the relevant display component.

Answer (score 2):

In case of label's you can simply set font as follows:

```
JLabel welcomeLabel= new JLabel(); 
welcomeLabel.setFont(new Font("Name Of Font Suitable Font", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 100)); 
welcomeLabel.setText("Welcome");
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for pointing that out. Mentioned "Arial" for reference. Modified the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `JTextArea`, you can do this:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setFont(textArea.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
```

or

```
textArea.setFont(textArea.getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC));
```

For better text formatting support, you may use `JTextPane`.

Answer (score 0):

The Swing text component supports HTML 3.2 and a pretty good subset of CSS 1.0. Basically you can use those languages with a wide range of various components, such as buttons, menu items, labels, text panes, editor panes, tool tips a.s.o.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      JFrame f=new JFrame();
      UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", false);
      JLabel l=new JLabel("<html><center><b>You can make bold the font with tag b</b><br>" + "<i>You can make italic the font with tag i</i><br>"+"<font color=#42bcf4>You can change the color</font><br>"+"<i><b><font color=#42bcf4>You can combine the tags</font></b></i><br>...");
      f.getContentPane().add(l);
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.pack();
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(l);
      f.setVisible(true);

}
```

(Setting UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", false); is important since by default the default look and feel in java swing (Metal look and feel) makes text bold by default. If you're using a different plaf, no need for that line)